# Prophecy автодополнение в PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, плагин, phpunit

Пользуюсь PhpStorm и [Prophecy](https://github.com/phpspec/prophecy) в тестах PHPUnit.

Использовал плагин [PHPUnit Autocomplete Assistant](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7722) и он работал хорошо до обновления до PhpStorm 2016.1.1. Плагин выключился и при загрузке PhpStorm показывает:

> Following plugins are incompatible with current IDE build: PHPUnit Autocomplete Assistant

Автор уже давно не отвечает на его [GitHub issues](https://github.com/maxfilatov/phpuaca/issues/21) поэтому я начал искать альтернативы, но пока ничего не нашёл. Без такого плагина пользоваться Prophecy в PhpStorm очень неудобно - куча ложных предупреждений, автодополнение не работает.

Есть ли другие подобные инструменты для PhpStorm и Prophecy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полчаса назад сделали форк, который работает под последнюю версию:
https://github.com/shopfe/phpuaca/releases/tag/1.3.2-beta

shopfe сделал также pull request, но его пока не приняли
https://github.com/maxfilatov/phpuaca/pull/22

Пока можно удалить оригинальный плагин и установить форк. PhpStorm даёт установить плагин с диска с zip-файла:
`Settings > Plugins > Install plugin from disk...`